# How can i echo data to checkbox field using JQuery Mobile and php?

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile, checkbox

In `viewsessions.php`, I am attempting to select multiple values from a db and insert it into grouped checkbox fields (eg. typeofactivity, employer, date, time, amount as one single checkbox field) using `<input type="checkbox" name="example" id="example">` or similar in JQuery mobile, so that when displayed on the hmtl page, various checkboxes can be selected to send to another page. So far, i have managed to display the contents of the db using a table, but can't find a working solution to display the data in checkboxes?

Any ideas greatly appreciated! :)

Code so far:
**viewsessions.php**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "cornwall";

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','cornwall','ibill');
// This code creates a connection to the MySQL database in PHPMyAdmin named 'ibill':

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// The connection is then checked, if it fails, an echo is sent back to the page stating a connection error.

$viewsessions = "SELECT typeofactivity, employer, date, time, amount FROM session_details";
$result = $con->query($viewsessions);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr>
                    <th>Type of Activity</th>
                    <th>Employer</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Amount (GBP)</th>
                </tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row["typeofactivity"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["employer"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["date"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["time"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["amount"]."</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: I don't exactly get the view that you are talking about.You mean the view will be like on each row  one check box on the left and on the right displaying datas of typeofactivity, employer, date, time, amount etc  and also if check box gets checked it should hold values of typeofactivity, employer, date, time, amount etc.

Comment: Hi @Kiran Muralee. Basically I want the user to be able to select individual sessions with the aid of a checkbox on the right side of the screen which will then be sent to another page. Each session will consist of the values typeofactivity, employer, date, time, amount. The user checks the box for which sessions they want to send and submits the chosen sessions.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .$row['typeofactivity']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['employer']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['date']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['time']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['amount']. "</td>";
echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='' id='checkbox' /></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```